# Pandas DataFrameGroupBy export to Excel

Tags: python, pandas, export-to-excel, sql-insert

I'm trying to export the count of grouped records to Excel.

I have CSV file that looks like this:

```
Date        Country   Sub  Source
2014-09-11    US      1    source1
2014-09-11    US      2    source2
2014-09-11    UK      1    source3
2014-09-11    US      1    source1
2014-09-11    IN      3    source4
```

I need the grouped count of records by Country, Sub and Source.

```
df = pd.read_csv('log.csv',sep='\t')
count = df.groupby(['Country','Sub','Source']).size()
count.to_excel('report.xls', index=False)
```

But I get an error when I run it: `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'to_excel'`

Is exporting a DataFrameGroupBy to Excel not allowed?
Also is there a way to insert grouped records with the count info into a MySQL database?

Comment: You could just wrap the Series into a dataframe: `pd.DataFrame(count).to_excel('report.xls', index=False)`

Comment: Just did that, now I'm trying to add grouping columns because output shows only count number.

Comment: For sql, see http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#sql-queries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the docs [groupby](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) returns a *GroupBy* object. The [to_excel](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) operation can only be performed on `DataFrame`. You can cast the *GroupBy* object to a `DataFrame` and then call the `to_excel` function

Comment: `groupby` does *not* return a series, but the `.size()` method of the groupby object does. To convert a Series to a DataFrame, you can also use the `to_frame()` method.

Comment: how cast  GroupBy object to a DataFrame ?

Answer (score 8):

```
df = pd.read_csv('log.csv',sep='\t')
df = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(['Country','Sub','Source']).size(),columns=['Count'])
```

You'll get:

```
                     Count
Country Sub Source        
IN      3   source4      1
UK      1   source3      1
US      1   source1      2
        2   source2      1
```

then save to excel by:

```
df.to_excel('output.xls')
```